# How to push a UITableView from within a DetailView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

I'm building an app that uses UICollectionView to display an array of blog posts.

When the user taps on a post, a DetailView is pushed to show the post's content.

Within the Detail View, one can see a post picture, text etc. There is also a button to show comments.

I want the user to be able to tap on the `comments` button and load a UITableView that will show all comments written for that post. This is the part I'm unable to implement.

I've created a UITableView with interface builder and connected it to the DetailView using a segue. When the `comments` button is tapped, I get an empty table.

On my DetailView tapping the comments button triggers this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showComments"]) {

        NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
        NSArray      *commentThread  = [post objectForKey:@"comment"];

        // how do I pass the commentThread to the UITableView at the other end of the segue?
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to get this done? Glad to post more code.

This is my `CommentViewController.m`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"commentCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *comment       = [self.commentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString     *commentText   = [comment objectForKey:@"comment_text"];
    NSString     *commentAuthor = [comment objectForKey:@"comment_author"];

    cell.textLabel.text = commentText;

    return cell;

    NSLog(@"%@", comment);
}
```

And `CommentViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CommentViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *commentArray;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) id commentArray;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you create a controller for your UITableView?

I may not be understanding your design goal correctly so sorry if this seems like a basic answer, but if you are performing an seque, then you should initialize the tableview controller and set your datasource in some manner.

for example, in your prepare for segue, you should have something like this:

```
CommentsControllerView *myTableView = segue.destinationViewController;
myTableView.commentsArray = self.commentsArray;
myTableView.itemId = self.itemId;
```

in your custom tableview controller, you might create a NSArray property to hold the comments array and setup your tableview per standard procedures.  Or you would use some logic to retrieve the appropriate comments and load the tableview datasource for your new tableview. When it initializes it will have the data in it that you passed it and then it should operate just like a standard tableview using tableview delegate and datasource methods.

does that help?  hope so.

Comment: @CocoaaEv - I did create a controller for the UITableView called `CommentsControllerView.h/m` -- both were created based on UITableView so they contain a bunch of template code -- the code you offered, should it go in the DetailView where the button is?

Comment: the code above goes in your prepare for segue method in the controller  that provides the comments button.  I think you want to push a tableview of comments after the comment button is pushed.  When the button is pushed, you would call perform segue with identifier with the correct segue name.   Also, make sure in your storyboard you assign your new controller to your tableview controller in the object inspector. Then in your prepare for segue, you would pass in either the actual comments or some type of identifier so you can get the actual comments for that item.

Comment: that's very helpful @cocoaev - so far I've set everything up and have no errors -- I've added code from  `CommentViewController.m` in the OP - no errors but the table still appears blank as if data is not being passed - `NSLog` also does not output anything - what's missing?

Comment: hi torr - check to make sure that you set your tableview delegates properly.  you can accomplish in either in code or storyboard.  in code it would be something like this: self.tableView.delegate = self; self.tableView.datasource = self; also - another trick is hardcode a couple of entries in your tableview datasource to make sure things are hooked up correctly and working.  once its working with the hardcoding, swap back in the "passed" data.  Also, you can nslog your data just before and just after passing it in to validate you are passing data correctly. hope that helps.